# How to implement Inversify JS on Vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ecmascript-6

I always get this error

> service is undefined

This is my service which binds all services

```
import { Header } from "../Header/header";
import { HeaderService } from "../Services/header-app-service";
import { createContainer, asClass, InjectionMode } from "awilix";
import { Container, decorate, injectable, inject } from "inversify";
import "reflect-metadata";

export class RegisterService {
    get getContainer() {
        const container = new Container();
        container.bind(HeaderService).to(HeaderService).inSingletonScope();
        container.bind(Header).to(Header);
        container.resolve(Header);
    }
}
```

And in this class I expect to get service in the constructor.

```
export class Header extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(service) {
        super();
        debugger
        if (service) {
            const headerService2 = service.getData();
        }
        this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
        fetch("../CORE/Header/header.html").
            then(response => response.text()).then(content => {
                this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = content;
                this.createMenu(this.shadowRoot);
            });
    }
}
```

I want to know how to implement properly DI with inversify JS on Vanilla js